# Special character not saved in MS SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I have a small problem with this Czech character `ů`. This little bugger won't save into my MS SQL table when the update is triggered from my C# code.

If I manually add it in SQL Management Studio it is saved as it should, and it is also shown on the website as normal.

But the process of saving it from C# only ends in the character `u` beeing saved in the table and not `ů`.

My DB fields are of type `nvarchar` and `ntext` and the collation of the DB is `French_CI_AS`. I'm using MSSQL 2008.

Code:

```
SqlCommand sqlcomLoggedIn = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table SET id = 1, title = 'Title with ů' WHERE id = 1", sqlCon, sqlTrans);
int status = sqlcomLoggedIn.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use [command parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you aren't using a unicode literal; it would have to be:

```
UPDATE Table SET id = 1, title = N'Title with ů' WHERE id = 1
```

the `N` is important.

The **much bigger** issue is that you should be using parameters:

```
int id = 1;
string title = "Title with ů";
// ^^ probably coming from C# parameters

using(var sqlcomLoggedIn = new SqlCommand(
    "UPDATE Table SET title = @title WHERE id = @id", sqlCon, sqlTrans))
{
    sqlcomLoggedIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
    sqlcomLoggedIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", title);
    int status = sqlcomLoggedIn.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

then the problem goes away, you get to use cached query plans, *and* you avoid sql injection

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm :)

Comment: @Martin (quietly hopes you used the second version, not the first)

Comment: I actually used parameters :)